# Spring Autorwiring on JAXWS Endpoint does not work

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to develop a SOAP web servie using JAXWS (from JDK 7). The problem I am facing is with autowiring. I tried with `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext` which was suggested in many blogs; but its not working. The autowired beans are still NULL. My environment is:

```
JDK: 1.7.0_75
Spring: 4.1.7.RELEASE1
JAXWS-API: 2.2.11
JAXWS-RT: 2.2.10
JAXB-API: 2.2.12
```

**web.xml** entry

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:spring/wsApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <description>Spring Application Context listener. This must be loaded first</description>
  <display-name>Spring Context Config Listener</display-name>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
  <description>JAX-WS Listener. This will initialize Metro web service engine</description>
  <display-name>JAX-WS Listener</display-name>
  <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JAX-WS Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JAX-WS Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**sun-jaxws.xml** Entry

```
<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>
  <endpoint
    name="BookService"
    implementation="com.demo.ws.endpoint.BookServiceEndpointImpl"
    wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdls/book-service.wsdl"
    service="{http://demo.app/services/book}BookService"
    port="{http://demo.app/services/book}BookServicePort"
    url-pattern="/services/books" />
</endpoints>
```

**classpath:/spring/wsApplicationContext.xml** entry

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

**BookServiceEndpointImpl.java** (the web service endpoint)

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.demo.ws.artifacts.BookServicePort")
public class BookServiceEndpointImpl implements BookServicePort {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(AppConstants.BOOK_SERVICE_BEAN)
  private BookService bookService;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PostConstruct completed...");
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

    logger.debug(">>>>>> bookService --> {}", bookService);
  }

  // ... The endpoint methods.
}
```

The above log lines are printed in log file, however the `bookService` is printed `null`.

Could someone help how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you declare somewhere your BookService class, to be spring managed ? Or maybe add the @Configurable annotation on your BookService class or declare as in xml file. Spring need to know it for autowired it.

Comment: @PupCode, yes I have `@Component(AppConstants.BOOK_SERVICE_BEAN)` on `BookService` class. In Spring's log file, I could see all my beans getting initialized.

Comment: If i remember correctly, the target class to autowired a Field, need to be spring managed too. Try @Configurable on your BookServiceEndpointImpl class, You have a WebService annotation, but i don't know if spring know it ?

Comment: @PupCode, `@Configurable` is not working. The `bookService` instance is still `null`. The blogs are telling the following statement will let spring know about this class. `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)`.

Comment: Yes, but you call it after the class creation, maybe you need do to this just after class creation ... An another way is trying to Autowired the ApplicationContext in your class, and call getBean on it, for debug purpose ?

Comment: Well, I had to do a hack to get my app work, but the auto wiring is still not working. So, I created a class called `SpringAppContextManager` which implements `ApplicationContextAware` and overrides the `setApplicationContext()` method. And, I hold a static reference to this application context inside this class and retrieved beans through this. But I am not convinced with this solution.